# How can I make a GridView with Horizontal scrolling?

Tags: java, android, gridview, kotlin

How can I do that?

I made `android:scrollbars="horizontal"`, but it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview to perform horizontal or vertical scrolling in a gridView.

Some of attributes available are

```
scrollDirectionPortrait (vertical | horizontal) 
scrollDirectionLandscape (vertical | horizontal)
```

Here is an example of usage

```
<com.jess.ui.TwoWayGridView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#E8E8E8"
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
app:cacheColorHint="#E8E8E8"
app:columnWidth="80dp"
app:rowHeight="80dp"
app:numColumns="auto_fit"
app:numRows="auto_fit"
app:verticalSpacing="16dp"
app:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
app:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
app:scrollDirectionPortrait="vertical"
app:scrollDirectionLandscape="horizontal"
app:gravity="center"/>
```